# Unescape JSON strings with JSON_TABLE in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

I have trouble with the `JSON_TABLE` function in **MariaDB 10.6.5**. This is my query:

```sql
SET @data = '[{"Data": "<root language=\\"de\\"></root>"}]';

SELECT
  data
FROM JSON_TABLE (@data, '$[*]' COLUMNS (data text PATH '$.Data')) AS t;
```

What I get back is the XML string, but not properly unescaped:

```xml
<root language=\"de\"></root>
```

When I use then `JSON_VALUE` instead:

```sql
SET @data = '[{"Data": "<root language=\\"de\\"></root>"}]';

SELECT
  JSON_VALUE(@DATA, '$[0].Data');
```

then I get back the correctly unescaped string:

```xml
<root language="de"></root>
```

When I do the same on a MySQL **8.0.26** server, it works as expected:

```sql
SET @data = '[{"Data": "<root language=\\"de\\"></root>"}]';

SELECT
  data
FROM JSON_TABLE (@data, '$[*]' COLUMNS (data text PATH '$.Data')) AS t;

-- correct:
-- <root language="de"></root>

SELECT
  JSON_VALUE(@data, '$[0].Data');

-- correct:
-- <root language="de"></root>
```

It looks to me that this difference in behaviour is a bug in MariaDB's side. Any hints on how to get that working in MariaDB?

Comment: Certainly looks like a bug since `"` are escaped as if they are part of JSON string but then the outer quotes are not there.

Comment: Since it clearly looks like a bug when compared to MySQL 8.0.26 I've filed an issue in the MariaDB JIRA: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27412

Comment: 10 months later this bug is still open and there is no feedback from the MariaDB dev team about it.